# Calling methods that are nested inside classes

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, typeerror

I'm using all programs that come stock with the GNU based OS (Precise Puppy 5.4)

## Description

- First I create a class.
- Inside that class I define a method
- This method takes a generically named argument
- Inside i have an `if-elif-else` statement that works with the argument value
- The `if` statement determines which string to return

Outside of the class I prompt user input that is passed to variable `userinput`.

I then call the method with `userinput` as an argument and assign the return to
a variable name `variable`.
Then I print `variable`.

## A few notes

First, I understand that there are other ways to achieve the same effect. The reason
I don't use one of them is because I'm making a fairly large text adventure and will need 
to make a very large amount of decisions and assign a very large number of variables.

It would be much easier to work with the code if I were to classify the different sections 
of the game (i.e.: a class named `Player` and methods named `stats`, `inventory`, `gold`, etc.) using
classes as categories and methods as specific areas

I know that the error is related to the fact that when I call the `class.function`, the class has no return value. But the method is not called inside the class so there's no way to return the value from the method inside of the class but outside of the method.

```
class classname () :
    def methodname (value) :
        if value == 1 :
            return "Hello World"
        else :
            return "Goodbye World!"
userinput = raw_input("Enter the number [1]\n")
variable = classname.methodname (userinput)
print (variable)
```

the console output

```
Enter the number [1]        (this is the prompt)
1                           (this is the user input)

(now the error)

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "filename.py", line 8, in <module>
        variable = (classname.methodname (userinput))
TypeError: unbound method methodname() must be called with
classname instance as first argument (got classobj instance
instead)
```

This problem has been resolved. the issue was a simple syntax issue. here is the fixed code
Props to max for the solution and Lev Levitsky for formatting this post! ^.^

```
class classname () :
    def methodname (self, value) :
        if value == "1" :
            return "Hello World"
        else :
            return "Goodbye World!"
userinput = raw_input("Enter the number [1]\n")
variable = classname().methodname (userinput)
print (variable)
```

Comment: You have way too many parenthesis in there; you cal soose almost all of those.

Comment: they make it easier for me to read. i know i dont need them

Comment: @MartijnPieters there,,, i fixed the parenthesis lol

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen ..or may be not. Oops, it seems like I accidentally overwrote your edit, sorry.

Comment: @LevLevitsky no worries... i like your format better anyways =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Just add `@staticmethod` before `def methodname(value)` ;)

or, if you didn't intend to use a static method, try changing the signature of methodname to accept one additional parameter self (`def methodname (self, value) :`) and be sure to always call `methodname` from instances: `variable = (classname().methodname (userinput))`.

Comment: what is static method supposed to do that will fix the problem?

Comment: it makes the method a class method instead of an instance method

Comment: i assume that static method is what i want. i need it so i can sort the code to be more... classified, so to say

Comment: When a method is not static, you have to instanciate the class before using it. That is what the 'classname()' in Max's answer does. Declaring a method as static makes it callable without instanciation.

Comment: Thing is, if you plan to use only this type of functions (static), why not just use modules to organize your functions ?

Comment: Konner Rasmussen, the more 'pythonic' way to structure functions is to  put them in different packages; not make them static methods.

Comment: @MarcDemierre because im still a bit of a newbie to python and havent experienced how modules can organize the code

Comment: @Vladimir first, you use methods and functions like their two different things. are they not the same?

Comment: I think you should read the official documentation about packages and modules : http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html. It explains these concepts really well.

Comment: here's an old post on the topic of static methods and class methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python

Comment: Yes and classes to see the difference : http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: def methodname (self, value) and classname() fixed it, going to edit the post with the fixed code =)... and thanks for pointing me to packages and modules

Comment: it wont let me vote max up, please see that this is done... =)

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt and very helpful resposes! linuxquestions == fail.... stackoverflow == epic =D